# Move forward in a screen by accessing the node info

Tags: android, accessibility

I have an android application in which i am downloading the apk from web server and store it in local storage after storing in externel storage. I open the apk file programmatically and then I install the apk programmatically. This is my code for installing the app programmatically.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.ariaware.store.fileProvider", file_path); // Here filepath is location of apk file in local storage
    intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

} else {
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file_path), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
}
startActivityForResult(intent, INSTALL);
```

This code takes me to this Screen. Please have a look here. There are two options install and cancel on this screen. Now user needs to click on install in order to install the app.[image]

In order to move to next screen before clicking. I started an accessibility service that takes content of the screen and then move forward according to the screen contents
This is code to open accessibility services

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(intent,ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
```

This is code for the service that i used for automatically install.

```
if (nodeInfo != null) {
            int childCount = nodeInfo.getChildCount();
            if ("android.widget.Button".equals(nodeInfo.getClassName())) {
                String nodeContent = nodeInfo.getText().toString();
                Log.d("TAG", "content is " + childCount+nodeContent);
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(nodeContent)
                        &&( "install".equals(nodeContent.toLowerCase())
                        || "done".equals(nodeContent.toLowerCase())
                        || "open".equals(nodeContent.toLowerCase())
                     )

                ) {
                    nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if ("android.widget.ScrollView".equals(nodeInfo.getClassName())) {
                nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                AccessibilityNodeInfo childNodeInfo = nodeInfo.getChild(i);
                if (iterateNodesAndHandle(childNodeInfo)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }


                 }
```

The main function is `nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);` which is automatically start installation. Have a look at this [link. Here I posted the video. What is happening?](https://youtu.be/s07whT-la_k)
So afer watching the video u will came to know that gets auto install but after installing it asks for open or done.. I want to move forward from this screen. I performed all these action when app installed screen appears but nothing happens

```
                nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD);
                nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
                nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_NEXT_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY);
                nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_DISMISS);
```

My primary goal is to move forward when app got installed.It shouldn't struck on screen either u want to open or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When textview content becomes equal to app installed or not installed. You should clear the  top stack and start current activity again

```
  if(nodeInfo.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("App installed.") ||
                                nodeInfo.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("App not installed.")
                        ||        nodeInfo.getText().toString().contains("couldn't be installed. Free up some space and try again.")
                        )
                        {

                            Intent intent=new Intent(MAIN,MainActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
}
```